# Parsing Tex using python re library

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to parse the following part of a .tex file

```
\section{a}
some random lines with lot 
of special characters
\subsection{aa}
somehthing here too
\section{b}
```

I want the content within `\section{a}` and `\section{b}` inclusive so i tried the following code in python

```
import re
a="my tex string mentioned above"
b=re.findall(r'\\section{a}.*\\section{b}',a)
print(b)
```

but i got `b=[]`. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the re.DOTALL flag to make the . match newlines, like this:

```
b=re.findall(r'\\section{a}.*\\section{b}',a,re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the curly braces as metacharacters be escaped with `\{`?

Comment: @halex It seems many parsers treat them as literals, if they don't have a number inside.